# Django href for html

Tags: django

How i can make link to this urls.py? I tried to pass the link through all the methods I know but they don't work and gave an error

```
    path('category/<slug:gender_slug>/<slug:category_slug>/', views.StuffCategory.as_view(), name='category'),
```

html:

```
{% get_genders as genders %}
                    {% for gender in genders %}
                <li>
                    <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                    <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Категории <span class="fa fa-angle-down"
                                                                       aria-hidden="true"></span> </label>

                    <a href="/">{{ gender }} <span class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2">

                    <ul>
                        {% get_categories as categories %}
                        {% for category in categories %}
                        <li><a href="/">{{category.name}}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
                    {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
class StuffCategory(ListView):
    model = Stuff
    template_name = 'shop/shop.html'
    context_object_name = 'stuffs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Stuff.objects.filter(draft=False)
        if self.kwargs.get('category_slug'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['category_slug'])
        if self.kwargs.get('gender_slug'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(gender__slug=self.kwargs['gender_slug'])
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the parameters that have been defined in url as below:

```
<a href="{% url 'category' gender_slug=gender.slug category_slug=category.slug %}">{{category.name}}</a>
```

For more information refer to [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls)

Comment: gives an error message:
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'category' with keyword arguments '{'gender_slug': <Gender: Мужчинам>, 'category_slug': <Category: Футболки>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<gender_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']

Comment: I thought. Should have just passed "gender.slug"

Answer (score 1):

When trying to access a link with a `href` attribute you can simply use the `name` attribute of your `path` object that you defined in `urls.py`. You have to make sure, to submit every parameter the `path` object needs:

For example for an edit field:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'category' object.pk gender_slug=gender arg %}">
```

here:

- `category` is the name
- `object.pk` could be the primary key of the object transmitted to the template
- `gender_slug` & `arg` are additional parameters that are defined by your `path` object